# Compile output re-write

Tags: compile-mode

I'm working with an old compiler that puts out error lines like this:

```
./code\driver.c(327): WARNING C4200: Other...
```

I need to fix a couple things:

1. Fix the path from Wine/DOS mode to local: ./code\driver.c -> driver.c
2. Rewrite "Entering directory ..." lines
3. Rewrite the line info:  driver.c(327): -> driver.c:327
4. And keep everything after that intact

Anybody know a way to re-write compile output to be emacs compatible?

I ended up writing a Python script, but I wouldn't be surprised if there is something directly in emacs that can do all this.

Answer (score 1):

Is that output in the command line or in an emacs compilation buffer?

If it is in a compilation buffer in Emacs, then you just need to make this buffer
writeable again and then you can do text replacement with a couple of regex. Its
rather simple to stuff all that in a command.

i.e

```
(defun simple-cleanup-compile-buffer ()
  (interactive)        ;; mark as command, so it is callable via `M-x`
  (read-only-mode -1)  ;; make compile buffer writeable
  (goto-char 0)        ;; goto beginning of buffer
  (replace-regexp "\\([.A-z0-9]\\)\\\\\\([A-z0-9 ]\\)" "\\1/\\2")    ;; replace \ with /
  ;; more regexps here ...
  (read-only-mode 1))
```

Since you wrote that in phython, I guess you are able to figure out the other regexs
yourself.

This site on [Emacs Regexpressions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) might come in handy.

---

On the other hand, you could teach emacs how to interpret the compiler output.
Changing the variables `compilation-error-regexp-alist` and `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` could help.